# Is there any terraform module to create folders within a Bucket (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Is there any terraform module to create folders within a Bucket (GCP) ?
That is to say, I already know that with the module google_storage_bucket we can create GCS buckets in GCP. 
But, is there any way to create folders within a bucket (GCP) by using terraform ?

thanks,

Comment: There's no such thing as folders/directories in GCS (or indeed any S3 compatible storage). Instead keys can include `/` characters and these are then shown as if they have a directory structure. If you want to write `foo/bar/baz` to a GCs/S3 bucket then you can do that without `foo/bar/` existing. Read https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork for more information on this.

Answer (score 16):

So a quick answer to your question is: yes. You can use Terraform to effectively make an empty "directory" in a bucket. Here's how:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  name          = "my-really-awesome-test-bucket"
  location      = "us-east4"

  project       = "my-really-awesome-project"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "content_folder" {
  name          = "empty_directory/"
  content       = "Not really a directory, but it's empty."
  bucket        = "${google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket.name}"
}
```

Notice that you're creating an object with a trailing / at the end of the name. The content goes nowhere and is just there because the module requires it. And now when you log into the GCP console, you'll see the empty "directory" in the bucket and you can upload new objects into it.

**But there's some other stuff going on here that you should know.** Google Cloud Storage uses a flat file-system. This means that when you upload an object to the service, you aren't really creating a directory structure and storing your file inside. Instead you are creating a single file with the entire path (ex: *'/bucket_name/directory1/directory2/filename'*) as the entire file name. It's actually more technical than this, but that's a rough explanation.

Comment: A few weeks ago my teammate and I ran into a use-case where this was quite helpful, so I wouldn't call it pointless.

Comment: I don't think its pointless.  I logged into the GCP console and created a bucket.  In the bucket browser, there is the option to create a "folder".  I created a folder called "abc".  This resulted in an object called "abc/" being created.  If we then look here ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork we see that "rule 4" applies.  Seems useful to me (opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Object storage  is completely flat. There are no folders. When you see a folder in the UI or output from a command, it's just metadata describing how to show it to you.